# laravel cross domain auth cookies and filters

Tags: authentication, laravel-4, cross-domain

I have a laravel web server which is managing multiple domains, such as:

```
site1.domain.com, site2.domain.com, site3.domain.com
```

I have with great success added the site name to the user authentication process and thus have a single table of users each with respect to sites. There is no persistence of users across sites and they are considered unique. This works well.

For each site, there is a backend, eg.

```
site1.domain.com/office
```

For this, I have a different set of users of the model Admin. In order to make this work, I have a complately different set of auth paths, a different controller and all that. I achieve this with the following filter.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
  if ($request->is('office*'))
  {
    Config::set('auth.driver', 'eloquent.admin');
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
```

These admins are common across domains. That is to say that username is unique within admin model.

This works well, but needs to move on.

I would like login and logout to be consistent between sites. That is to say that if an admin has logged into one site office, they have logged into them all and that of they log out, they have logged out of them all.

I attempted to update my filter thus:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
  if ($request->is('office*'))
  {
    Config::set('auth.driver', 'eloquent.admin');
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');

    Config::set('session.path', '/office');
    Config::set('session.domain', '.domain.com'); // tried without leading . too
  }
});
```

However, if I analyse my cookies in my browser, the domain and path information has not been affected and remains as site.domain.com and / respectively.

Can you enlighten me as to how to change the session cookie attributes based on my request?

There is a site dependence. In as much as there is a many to many relationship between admin and site which determines is an admin can access the /office of a particular site.

I am concerned that is an admin is logged in, they will get access to any site office.

My intention is to write an additional filter "can admin this site" which will check the relationship.

Do you consider this a suitable measure on the context of the proposed cross domain auth for admins?

Comment: If you don't mind all users being shared between sites, you could just change cookie domain to `.domain.com`.
Other option is creating new authentication guard/model which generates/checks separate JWT cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you open `app/config/session.php` what driver are you using? Some, such as file don't seem to store the data across wild-card sub-domains.

I solves this by using Redis (if you're using Homestead, it should be already available to you):

```
'driver' => 'redis',

    'redis' => array(

    'cluster' => true,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

),
```

This is to do with how the different drivers use the hostname to reference the session data.